# Visual Studio Taco - Remotebuild will no longer deploy to remote device

Tags: ios, cordova, taco

Up until recently (around Sept. 15 2016) I was able to build and deploy a cordova project to a remote device (iPhone 6) using VS2015 with the latest version of TACO and remotebuild.

I am now running ios 10 and updated iTunes and xcode.

Now when I run a remotebuild the device prompts me to "Trust Computer." I tap the button and then nothing happens. Remotebuild thinks that the deploy was successful but nothing gets installed on the device so the "run" step fails. See the 404 below.

GET /cordova/build/1216/deploy 200 692.617 ms - 760

GET /cordova/build/1216/run 404 762.857 ms - 35

GET /cordova/build/1216/debug 500 10014.728 ms - 88

If I open the xcode project and run from there it installs successfully on the device and is able to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this resolved. I found the fix here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/5

The solution was upgrading brew, libimobiledevice, ideviceinstaller and ios-webkit-debug-proxy. I typed the following commands into terminal:

```
brew update
brew upgrade libimobiledevice --HEAD
brew upgrade ideviceinstaller ios-webkit-debug-proxy
```

Comment: Thanks, your link helped me alot, had to overwrite etc, but managed to get it working