# Visual Studio 2017 cannot send code to Mac using Taco Remotebuild

Tags: macos, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I know this question had been asked hundrets of times, but the solutions provided did not help me.

I now have installed Visual Studio Professional 2017 (previously Professional 2015), build 15.9.17 with Apache Cordova. I click on 'Release' --> 'iOS' --> 'Remote Device' in my project. In the platforms folder I deleted the previous ios folder beforehand.

On my Mac (High Sierra) I have installed Taco Remotebuild, created a Remotebuild.config with the following entries: "appLaunchStepTimeout": 600000, "emulatorLaunchTimeout": 600000. I also ran `chmod 777 /Users/micha/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds`.

Now I am starting `remotebuild --secure false` on my Mac and after a while I can see that my Visual Studio connects to the Mac. However after a while it says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   Error     An error occurred uploading to the build server
>   http://192.168.178.35:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=release&options=--device:
>   Timeout for operation exceeded (translated from German "Timeout für
>   Vorgang überschritten")   My-famous-program 6.0.1     1   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   Error     An error occured connecting to the build machine: The build url
>   cannot be null.   My-famous-program 6.0.1     1   1

Note: Both computers are connected using Wifi; a physical connection is not possible. On each computer Node.js with version 8.16.2 is running; a newer version is not possible due to other dependencies.

What do I have to do to have this running?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does the cordova folder get built on the MAC?  I can connect and it sends over the project, but because Microsoft doesn't support cordova in VS you need to manually create a project on the MAC and then copy your www that was passed from VS to your newly created project.  I found this works for me.

See this too: [Visual Studio Taco - Remotebuild will no longer deploy to remote device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605193/visual-studio-taco-remotebuild-will-no-longer-deploy-to-remote-device?rq=1)